# sharepoint search dont get items recursive

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-search

I have a sharepoint document library which contains multiple folder each with files and folders in it. I want to get only the items in the current folder when executing the query and thus **DON'T** get the items in the subfolders under it. the way i create the search is as follows:

The query part:

```
path:https://one365dev1.sharepoint.com/sites/Group100/Rodney%20Documenten/
```

2 example queries that i execute:

Root:

```
 https://one365dev1.sharepoint.com/_api/search/query?querytext='path:https:%2f%2fone365dev1.sharepoint.com%2fsites%2fGroup100%2fRodney%2520Documenten%2f'&clienttype='ContentSearchRegular'
```

A subfolder:

```
https://one365dev1.sharepoint.com/_api/search/query?querytext='path:https:%2f%2fone365dev1.sharepoint.com%2fsites%2fGroup100%2fRodney%2520Documenten%2ftester'&clienttype='ContentSearchRegular'
```

The main problem is that it returns all sub folders and items and also includes its own folder. Does anyone have an idea how to solve this?

thanks in advance and any help is much appreciated.
Cheers!

Comment: Do you have to use the Search API to do this?

Comment: I think it's my only solution as I am exposing it in an angular front-end. If you have any other solution that's alright too. thanks

Comment: I just saw that you commented back. I can't give a solution yet, as I'm not at a computer. but don't be discouraged, what you want to do is very possible, and simple